# Anaconda prompt install package error (UnsatisfiableError)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, command-prompt

I want to install package ta-lib.

I use google and get this link 
https://anaconda.org/Quantopian/ta-lib

To install this package with conda run:

```
conda install -c quantopian ta-lib
```

so i type this in Anaconda prompt,but i get

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - python 3.6*
>     - ta-lib -> numpy 1.10* -> python 2.7*
>   Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I hoped i can install through Anaconda, and i am not familiar with install command.

My PC: Win10  x64   python 3.6.1

Comment: Can run `pip list` to display the list of installed package. And `python --version`?

Comment: run `pip list`   and then?i dont know your mean . `python version is 3.6.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package is not available for Python 3.6. You need to create a new conda environment to install it:

```
conda create -n ta-lib-env -c quantopian python=3.5 ta-lib
```

You can see this by looking at the "Files" tab on the page you linked and inspecting the file names

Comment: after input that command.i still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'`

Comment: Did you activate the environment? `activate ta-lib-env`

Comment: I have type activate ta-lib-env in anaconda prompt.
Then i open jupyter notebook, `import talib` error still happened.
I think i had installed talib.

Comment: this is what after type your command.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/11jMxyk-w30BJg81fwp5J2psZomRXJ8jd5Gq1AO_pN8Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want to run a Jupyter Notebook (which you didn't say in the question...) then you also need to install `ipykernel` and choose to create a new Notebook with the kernel from this environment.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know that is important thing.
I just type `pip install ipykernel` in anaconda prompt.
But what you say is almost out of range that i had already know,
I started to be confused in this problem.

Comment: Don't use `pip` to install packages that are available with Conda. It can cause conflicts and Conda cannot manage packages installed with pip. You should `pip uninstall ipykernel` and then `conda install ipykernel`

Comment: i have done what you tell me.`pip uninstall ipykernel` and  `conda install ipykernel` had been run under anaconda prompt.
I am not clear your mean about   create a new Notebook with the kernel from this environment.
The pictures show my jupyter notebook.
1. https://imgur.com/a/perbN
2. https://imgur.com/a/2d7o0
I can't find any different after install that.

Comment: Or did you have any other recommanded development environment ?

Comment: Did you install the kernel into the environment you created? In other words, did you install the kernel after you activated the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Or this method will do！

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
pip install numpy
pip install TA-Lib 
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall TA-Lib
```

Comment: You can format code blocks by highlighting them and pressing `CTRL+K` (Windows) or `⌘+K` (OS X). The `+` symbol will convert it to a bullet list, which shouldn't be used for code snippets.